# Difference b/w Objective C's self and C++'s this?

Tags: c++, objective-c

can someone tell the difference between objective C's self and C++ this pointer?

Comment: What do your Objective-C and C++ references tell you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning to self in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341734/assigning-to-self-in-objective-c)

Comment: Kirill V. Lyadvinsky: It's not a duplicate of that question.  The questioner there already understood the answer to this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main difference is that `this` is a keyword, while `self` is a variable. The result of this is that while `this` *always* refers to the object that is executing a particular method, Objective-C methods are free to modify `self` during execution. This is sometimes used by constructors, which set `self = nil` on failure.

The reasons for doing so are:

- so that subclasses (which chain initialisers with `self = [super init]`) can see when the initialisation fails and know not to carry on in their own initialisers.
- composing objects can see the failure and know that they don't have a valid component.

Some initialisers will set `self` to a different, but valid, object. This can be used in class clusters, where the "abstract" class can generate a temporary instance while building the initialised object, but ultimately return a different object based on the properties that were built up during construction.

In addition, it means that you can do the usual things with variable names that confuse everyone that you can't do with keywords, such as defining a more local variable with the same name `self` in a code block.

Comment: In C++, you *can* modify the value of this. Not saying that you should, but I've seen it used to pack some extra info on a system where 32 bits pointer wasn't fully used by memory mappings...

Comment: @jv42: my compiler doesn't allow that without setting an option, so I assumed it was either non-standard or anachronistic.

Comment: @jv42: `this` is an rvalue, it cannot be modified.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  One is spelt s-e-l-f.  The other is spelt t-h-i-s.

Less facetiously:

`self` is used in Objective-C classes to represent a pointer the current instance.

`this` is used in C++ classes to represent a pointer the current instance.

They perform analogous roles but on entirely different structures.

Comment: @Preet Sangha: And what is wrong with having a joke in the answer?

Comment: Lol. I wrote joke because I was too lazy to look up how to spell facetiously once I'd removed it. And to answer your question nothing at all.