# error: Use of undeclared identifier 'self' c++-objective c mixing

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, mixing

I'm currently finishing my game for iOS using ue4. I'm using some specific iOS Code and try to call Methods using the 'self' variable

```
void Aaccessactorios::Shareoption() {
    [self Sharebutton];//ios                 
}
```

the Code is within a prepocessor tag #if PLATFORM_IOS and #endif

I think that I've declared  the self variable at the start of my cpp file:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```

Other Forums Mention that Unreal engine compiles all the cpp .mm at the end, so I don't think that's the issue.

the self variable is used all around the objective c part, so it is crucial to my Code. How do I mix the Code properly and get my self variable to be declared?

Thank you

edit: this is the part i try to recreate https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/422323/callback-from-objective-c-back-to-the-c-layer.html

Comment: As far as I know, a class can't be both a C++ class and an Objective-C class. `self` is to Objective-C what `this` is to C++ - you don't declare it, it's provided for you by the language.( I also believe that your `init` should produce an error if it's in a .cpp file.)

Comment: `self` is undeclared identifier. What is unclear? Declare variable and assign object to it.

Comment: Note that the example you linked does not use `self` in a C++ class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mix C++ and Obj-C all the time. An Obj-C class instance is not the same as a C++ instance. A C++ class instance has `this`. There is no `self`. Obj-C class instance has `self`. You can read more about it here:

[Difference b/w Objective C's self and C++'s this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810824/difference-b-w-objective-cs-self-and-cs-this)

Assuming from what you have written, you have a C++ class `Aaccessactorios`. It is not clear who has defined `Sharebutton`. If it is in the C++ class, then you would call it as

`this->Sharebutton();`

or simply

`Sharebutton();`

If `Sharebutton` belongs to an Obj-C class, then you need to have the C++ either have a pointer to the Obj-C class instance, or have it passed into the function. An example of the latter would be:

```
void Aaccessactorios::Shareoption(ObjCClassObj *obj) {
    [obj Sharebutton];//ios                 
}
```

In that code reference link, you can see they actually do the former.

```
 class IOSMediaPlayerController
 {
 public:
     IOSMediaPlayerController();
     ~IOSMediaPlayerController();
     void startPlayback();
     void stopPlayback();
     void callbackFunc();

     #if PLATFORM_IOS
     IOSMediaPlayerControllerObj *playerObj;
     #endif    
 };
```

Here you can see that `playerObj` is a reference (pointer) to the Obj-C object. This created in the constructor with this

```
 IOSMediaPlayerController::IOSMediaPlayerController()
 {
     #if PLATFORM_IOS
     playerObj = [[IOSMediaPlayerControllerObj alloc] init];
     #endif
 }
```

And then gets invoked by

```
 void IOSMediaPlayerController::startPlayback()
 {
     #if PLATFORM_IOS
     [playerObj startPlayback];
     #endif
 }
```

Note the example code does not call `self`, it calls the constructor created instance `playerObj`.

Comment: got it to work by making a pointer to my desired class Otherclass*pointer= [[Otherclass alloc] init];