# understanding self. in objective C

Tags: objective-c

It's been 3 days since I've programmed in objective-C and I still don't quite understand the concept of self.

When should we use a self. in an implementation code?
If I understand this correctly if I have defined it as a property then I should use self.
But then the question is why? I've been reading many i-phone programming books but none doesn't seem to give me a strong and clear answer. Is self the same as this in other programming languages such as java?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341734/assigning-to-self-in-objective-c

Comment: And I thought that humans had innate self-awareness.

Comment: look this great tutorial http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/02/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is roughly equivalent to `this` in other languages. Also, the dot-notation introduced in Objective-C 2.0 can mask what is really happening.

```
self.foo = 4;
NSInteger someInt = self.foo;
```

The above is the same as

```
[self setFoo:4];
NSInteger someInt = [self foo];
```

`self` is actually just a variable that is automatically passed to class and instance methods. This is what makes it possible to do:

```
self = [super init];
if (!self) return nil;
```

Comment: nice explanation.... there is nice tutorial on this http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2011/02/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Answer (score 3):

`self` in Objective C is a pointer to the receiver of the current message, so it is a very similar concept to `this` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

**`self` in Objective-C is the same as `this` in Java.**

In both cases, `self` and `this` are special variables inside an object which refers to the object itself.  Use this when accessing properties or calling methods on the same object, or when calling an outside method to pass the object as a parameter.

If you think of `self` and `this` as the same thing, you will not have any problems.  Of course, you can't actually use them interchangeably since each language recognizes only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to programming in Java, **think of `self` as Java's `this`**.
 For example, you'd use `self` in a class when you want to refer to something to do with that class- for example, in the class Car, `self.wheels`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined a property and synthesised it using self.foo = bar will call a setter that has been generated for you. If you just do foo = bar you assign to your variable without going through the setter method. This means you won't take advantage of retain if the property was declared with retain or synchronisation.