# Two questions about objective-c: framework link and "self" in dot & square bracket expression

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, square-bracket, dot-operator

I am learning iphone dev now. Now I am reading book "iPhone 4 Development". During reading this book, I am confused about some syntax about objective-c used in this book. Ok, here are my questions:

- Link framework v.s. header file

At the end of chapter 7 of this book, the book mentions "link project to framework". In this book, it links to project to AudioToolbox.framework. I am wondering why not just add the header file  instead of linking framework? What's the difference between linking to a framework and adding a header file?

- "self" in dot & "[]" expression

In chapter 9 of this book, sample code uses dot operator and square bracket expression several times, for example:     `SecondLevelViewController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];` and     `SecondLevelViewController *nextController = [self.controllers objectAtIndex:row];` I think these two sentences have the same function. So when should I use "self"? When not?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: It would make more sense making two different questions (and this would have allowed you to find that your question is already answered) by which I mean, remove the part about the self operator (no use making it a question now you know it's a duplicate)

Comment: Here's the answer btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018459/understanding-self-in-objective-c not flagging because of the first part.

Comment: I think the questions are far enough apart to fly. The community is free to override me, however.

Answer (score 0):

Linking framework, just as in Visual Studio for Windows, tells your compiler where to find the libraries.

You then add the relevant include/import calls so that the compiler finds your class from imported library in the source, goes up the import/include, goes and hits the library, and back (more or less, it doesn't matter the exact behavior).

The question about self is a clear duplicate, check SO for "objective-c self"...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check for "object-c self".

Answer (score 0):

When you write `self.outlet = nil` the method `[self setOutlet:nil];` is called. When you write `outlet = nil;` you access variable outlet directly.

if you use `@synthesize outlet;` then method `setOutlet:` is generated automatically and it releases object before assigning new one if you declined property as `@property (retain) NSObject outlet;`.

Moved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254707/when-to-use-self-in-objective-c/7254766#7254766)

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get why use "self" in [self.controllers objectAtIndex:row]; ? Is it neccessary?

Comment: If you have variable `_controllers` that was syntesized using `@synthesize controllers = _controllers`, then you can only type `[_controllers smthHere];` or `[self.controlles smthHere]`.

Comment: Yes, @Nekto, you're right. Thank you! Also I found an article on through stackoverflow which said the same thing as you did:[link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html?lastPage=true#comment14967851)