# Objective-C initializers and overriding self

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about writing your own init methods in objective-c.  I've read a few different books and have seen a couple of ways to do it but the consensus is the right way to do it is like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init]; 
    if(self!=nil)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm a little confused about the line "self = [super init]".  My understanding is that, there's no guarantee that [super init] will return the class that you expect it to.  I think this is called "class clusters".  But in the normal case, where it does return the class you expect it to, if I set self to point to a class that is returned to me, aren't I just saying that self is referring to an object of a different class rather than the class that I'm in the init method of?

To summarize, why set self to be the superclass vs the actual class I'm in?

From a blog I read:

> The textbook reason is because [super
>   init] is permitted to do one of three
>   things:
>
> 1) Return its own receiver (the self
>   pointer doesn't change) with inherited
>   instance values initialized. 2) Return a
>   different object with inherited
>   instance values initialized. 3) Return
>   nil, indicating failure. In the first
>   case, the assignment has no effect on
>   self...

"The assignment has no effect on self" is what confuses me.  Why does it have no effect?  If I set something = to something else, shouldn't that have an effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning to self in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341734/assigning-to-self-in-objective-c)

Comment: I read that question but it mostly address the controversy rather than my lack of understanding about the assignment itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To summarize, why set self to be the superclass vs the actual class I'm in?

This is the Apple suggested way to do things, specifically due to the case of class clusters, as you say.

In general, you should not worry about the fact that `self` might be of a different class in the "normal" case.

`self` simply identifies the object you are, not the class (the class is actually a different object in the runtime). If you think of OO inheritance properties, it is at the same time an object of its class and of its superclass (if it is clear what I am trying to say). There is no contradiction in the "normal" case, since the value of `self` does not change.

Also, you can think of `self` as a special pointer to your object. In the cluster case, `self` can change, that is the reason why it can happen that its class change.

Hope this helps clarifying things. You will also find an interesting reading in this [article by Wil Shipley](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html).

Comment: If SubClass is a subclass of SuperClass, and in my init method I say self = [super init].  [super init] returns an instance of SuperClass.  I guess the part I'm confused about is, when you do the assignment, is it different than normal assignment?  Does the "=" sign mean something different because "self" is special?

Comment: You should differentiate `alloc` and `init`. `alloc` will reserve memory (i.e., physically create the object, so that `self` points to some memory area, and retain it); `init` is just a function call that does something in that memory region to initialize it to meaningful values. When you call superclass init, you are not creating an instance, just dealing with the "part" of that memory area that refers to the superclass. Likewise, subclass init deals with the "part" that it owns.

Comment: I understand that alloc reserves memory.  Is self just a pointer to that memory?  Is the answer then, because init could potentially return a DIFFERENT object in a DIFFERENT block of memory, I need to set self to point to that potentially DIFFERENT block of memory?  In the normal case, alloc returns the block of memory and the superclass init methods don't actually create anything new, they just initialize some stuff.

Comment: This is exactly my understanding. Another "special" case: when `super init` return nil due to self-deallocation (due to some abnormal condition, failure to allocate resources etc, init might release itself).

Answer (score 3):

There are different opinions on the proper way to write `-init` methods. There are two reasons that would make you think that `self = [super init]` is a good idea. (The assignment itself isn't anything special; Objective-C considers `self` to be a hidden parameter of the method, and you can reassign to parameters. The changed `self` only applies for the remainder of the method.)

### Superclass `-init` returns instance of different class

As you suggested, some classes use the "class cluster" pattern. However, in the most common implementation of this pattern, it's the `-alloc` method on the base class that is likely to return an instance of a different class, and it's all the `-init...` methods on the placeholder class that are likely to return an instance of a different class. `self = [super init]` is not useful here.

### Superclass `-init` returns a different instance of the same class

This is the reason that `self = [super init]` is recommended. Some classes have logic that allows `-init` to return a different instance than the one that it was called on. For example, some singleton classes in the Cocoa framework do this. But in almost every case, you need to know this behavior of the superclass in order to properly subclass it. [Here's an argument by Wil Shipley](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) that `self = [super init]` isn't actually very useful, because either `[super init]` returns `self` anyway, or the class you're subclassing is sufficiently complicated that reassigning self and then continuing with the initialization won't work anyway.

Comment: I think why I'm not understanding is, that I don't really understand what self = [super init] actually does.  I realize there's this controversy about whether or not it is correct, but I don't really understand what it does in the first place.  What does it mean to set the self parameter to something other than...well...self?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just edited to explain that. It's not magical in any way. It just says (in this case) that the rest of the `-init` method should initialize that object instead, and then that should be the final return value from `-init`, so it's the value that the caller will get, and all further methods will be called on that object.