# Shouldn't I use self->iVar = something; instead of iVar = something in my init

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

In ObjectiveC, recommended idiom of an init method is :

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myInstanceVariable = someConstant;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is because, superClass's init might return a different object than the current object, freeing the current object using [self release];

If that happens :

1) After the call to [super init] finishes, won't control return to original object's init method ?

2) And, won't the next line set myInstanceVariable of the original object ( on which, super-class called release) ?

And if this is the case, would changing the line to :

self->myInstanceVariable = someConstant;

help (so that, myInstanceVariable of the object returned by [super init] is set, instead of the original object) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It will, to do the assignment in the *if* condition.

2) By the time the *myInstanceVariable* is set, self already points to the new object, because the assignment in the *if* condition is done first. In fact the *myInstanceVariable* assignment is never processed if the assignment in the *if* condition is not successful.

Btw. as far as I can tell, all the direct calls to *myInstanceVariable* are resolved to:

*self->myInstanceVariable* anyway.

EDIT:
Just to address your question in the comments, take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341801/703809

Comment: Yes, `self->ivar` and `ivar` are exactly the same. A reference to `ivar` has an implicit `self->` attached to it.

Comment: From what I understood, self is just like any other local variable, it is a hidden parameter which is set to the object receiving the message at the runtime by the method invoking function.
Hence, didn't think ivar would resolve to self->ivar automatically. 
If it does, that means, we should never be assigning arbitrary values to self.

Comment: He's already answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289199/703809