# Why would [super init] ever return nil, when "super" is NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, init, super

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Objective-C why should I check if self = [super init] is not nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287950/in-objective-c-why-should-i-check-if-self-super-init-is-not-nil)

In Objective-C book i am reading, it is said that when `[init]` message is sent to `NSObject`, on occasion it may return `nil` and we should check the return value, before sending more messages to what may end up being a `nil`.

```
self = [super init];

if (self) {
 do stuff
}
```

I ask you though, what needs to happen for an `NSObject` to not be able to `init` itself?

Edit: Question specifically deals with an instance where YourClass:NSObject.

Comment: My question is specific to an case where your class's super class is NSObject itself.

Comment: The other question covers that case, and has a number of really excellent answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSObject` itself will never return nil on `init`, however other classes that inherit from it might, so it's considered good practice to always check the return value of `init`. For example, this will return nil:

```
 [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/a/file/that/does/not/exist"];
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that for classes where `[super init]` is never `nil`, it's unnecessary to put that check. This way you could, for example: `return [super initWithFoo:X baz:Y];`