# Setting Other Class Variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have 2 classes, ClassA and ClassB

ClassA has one BOOL variable set to No.

I am trying to set this variable to Yes from ClassB, but can't seem to figure out how to.

Below is the code I am using which doesn't work, it is simply what I would've thought would work, I have stripped out the unnecessary information:

Class A:

```
ClassA.h

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    BOOL boolean;
}

- (id) init;

ClassA.m

- (id) init {
    boolean = NO;
}
```

Class B:

```
ClassB.h

#import "ClassA.h"

- (IBAction) setBoolean: (id)sender;

ClassB.m

- (id) init {
    ClassA * theClassA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (IBAction) setBoolean: (id)sender {
    [theClassA boolean] = YES;
}
```

I hope this makes sense. I simply want to set the BOOL boolean in ClassA to YES from ClassB.

Comment: This code does not make much sense. Your `init`s are all wrong, as they do not assign to `self`; you are creating `theClassA` as a local variable that disappears as soon as your `init` is over; if your `ClassA` appears to be your `AppDelegate`, why would you create another instance of it?..

Comment: I'm still learning, the answer posted below solved my questions, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a property like that (`[object property] = value`). The proper syntax is `[object setProperty:value]` or `object.property = value`.

I wouldn't call a variable boolean. Might be misleading. Even though it's not the keyword for a boolean variable in Objective-C it is in a lot of other languages.

And you have to return the initialized object (self) in your init method (you have an id return type, not void):

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        boolean = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, you didn't specify an instance variable for theClassA in your ClassB implementation. You just create a local object and then leak it (you don't release it). Instead, declare it in your ClassB.h:

```
@class ClassA;
@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    ClassA *theClassA;
}
- (IBAction)setBoolean:(id)sender;
@end
```

Then initialize it like this:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         theClassA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And don't forget to release it in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [theClassA release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And one last thing. Having a method `- (IBAction) setBoolean: (id)sender` in your ClassB implies that ClassB has a property called `boolean`, which is not the case. I recommend renaming that method and/or rethinking your class designs.

Comment: You are missing the biggest issue: since `theClassA` is a *local* variable declared in another method, it's not available inside `setBoolean`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, thanks so much! Can I just ask why in the init method you declare self as [super init]? and why self should evaluate to true? I don't understand that part, but thanks again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287950/in-objective-c-why-should-i-check-if-self-super-init-is-not-nil