# What happens if you don't nil-check [super init] and try to initialize nil?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, null, self, super

I know this has been discussed previously, in this question for instance: [In Objective-C why should I check if self = [super init] is not nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287950/in-objective-c-why-should-i-check-if-self-super-init-is-not-nil)

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];    // Is potentially nil

    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code here…
    }

    return self;
}
```

I understand that `self` might be `nil`, but why does that matter? All answeres I've seen just say that `self` might be `nil` but do not explain why it matters. If you send a message to `nil` nothing will happen. You don't nil-check in any other code (except in some cases) so why do you need to do it in `init`?

Comment: `You don't nil-check in any other code (except in some cases)` - this statement scares me for your future

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin In Objective-C, one usually does not nil-check, except in `init...` methods.

Comment: @user3477950 well one is an objective-c developer and one can think of many hundreds of cases where one checks for nil. Just because it won't crash (not in all cases), doesn't mean nil is an appropriate value to receive. Would it be appropriate to display "(null)" to an end user? most certainly not

Comment: In addition to @SimonMcLoughlin, main scenario I can think of is you wouldn't want to store nil in an NSArray or NSDictionary.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin if you have to nil-check data that you are stuffing into user output, then you are pretty much doomed and need to change design.

Comment: @Jeff the same goes for your reasoning.

Comment: @user3477950 that is a ridiculous comment to make. There are many reasons why a design can't force that. Third party data you have no control over? Bugs (Both yours and third party), a file getting deleted missing some / all of the data, database issues, I could go on. There is a very well known programming principal of "failing gracefully", just because objective-c doesn't crash all of the time on nil's, doesn't take care of this for you. Bare minimum would be replacing nil's with default data or messages to the user to explain the situation

Comment: @user3477950 Such comments and attitude lead to very poor code and UI design, expecting the world to always be perfect for you

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin That's not the job of the presentation layer.

Comment: @user3477950 yes / no. At a high level should the presentation layer know to not place nil into a label? yes of course. At a low level should the business logic not equally know to not put bogus entires into the database, that it knows will force the presentation layer to  figure out a way to handle it, yes it should absolutely stop that from happening. Likewise with parsing data form servers or other sources, you should validate the data well before it hits the presentation layer. All integration points in / out of your control need to be validated

Comment: @user3477950 Otherwise your code is tightly coupled and when your business logic gets reused somewhere else, your forcing code duplication into the presentation layer or where ever else, opening up the risk to having the same bugs again and the increased work effort. Good, clean, reusable code should always nil check, no matter what layer its in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly convention, partly you're right, but it does depend on what you're going to setup using `self`.

In some cases you will be doing a lot of configuration, and creating all of that configuration when it won't actually be used is wasteful.

In some cases you may be passing `nil` to some configuration that will raise an exception when you do so, so checking and not making that call is sensible.

Following the convention is the safe and appropriate approach to take, and it really doesn't cost you anything (it's created for you by the template code).

Comment: it's not that easy, you only left out the #1 reason, which is instance variables. (for which I received 2 downvotes for some ambiguous reason...)

Answer (score 1):

> If you send a message to nil nothing will happen.

That's correct, because the runtime (messenger function) checks for `nil` before actually calling the method.

However, if you set `self` to `nil` **while** it's in the middle of a method call, any direct instance variable access will trigger a null pointer dereference:

```
self.myVar = ...;  // fine
_myVar = ...;     // fine

self = nil;

self.myVar = ...;  // fine
_myVar = ...;     // wrong
```

Comment: @newacct The (wrong and radical) edit of Wain introduced the word "exception". I've hunted down the word in the beginning of the answer, but it looks like I haven't found the second instance. (I myself have never asserted that it's going to be an exception, not even a segfault, since it isn't -- dereferencing a null pointer has undefined behavior, which I know very well, unless someone bungles into my post...)

Comment: I did not know this. I half didn't believe it until I tried it myself. Just a super-cool edge case. I say edge case since you can only assign `self` in an "method in the init family" and then you must forgo the `if(self)` check. You can really see the underlying struct-iness from the address that produces the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @NJones: "since you can only assign self in an "method in the init family"" in ARC that is